# R to return max and min dates for list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I used the following code to get the max and  min dates of the "dates" column of 3 different dataframes. I do not receive any output in my console?  Did I do it correctly, or do I need to create a separate function and use lapply?

```
df2 <- list(daily_activity,
+             hourly_activity,
+             sleep_day)
> for (i in 1:length(df2)){
+   max_date <- max(df2[[i]]$date)
+   min_date <- min(df2[[i]]$date)
+   return(c(max_date,min_date))
+ }
```

Comment: To get  output in the console, you can use `print()` instead of `return()`. A call to `return()` is used to return a result from a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Using the reproducible inputs in the Note at the end this gives a tibble whose first row is the minima and second row is the maxima.

```
library(purrr)

map_df(L, ~ range(.$date))
## # A tibble: 2 × 3
##   a          b          c         
##   <date>     <date>     <date>    
## 1 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 1970-01-01
## 2 1970-01-04 1970-01-04 1970-01-04
```

**2)** If  you want to specifically just fix up the code  in the question using `for` then iterate over the names and use `cat` to display the output.

```
for (nm in names(L)) {
   d <- L[[nm]]$date
   max_date <- max(d)
   min_date <- min(d)
   cat(nm, format(max_date), format(min_date), "\n")
}
## a 1970-01-04 1970-01-01 
## b 1970-01-04 1970-01-01 
## c 1970-01-04 1970-01-01
```

or shorter:

```
for (nm in names(L)) cat(nm, format(range(L[[nm]]$date)), "\n")
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(date = .Date(0:3), v = 0:3)
L <- list(a = DF, b = DF, c = DF)
```

Comment: Many thanks, I used the first method which is new to me and actually so much easier to apply.

Comment: In terms of the second method - did I make a mistake in the sense that  I wanted to use i instead of names, as I am not iterating over numeric values?

Comment: It is not wrong but it seems easier to use names.  If you want to use an index then `for(i in seq_along(L))` .

Comment: Many thanks, this was a great help!

Answer (score 0):

We may use `lapply` on the `list`

```
lapply(df2, function(x) c(max(x$date, na.rm = TRUE), 
      min(x$date, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Probably we can use `range(na.omit(x$date))` for shorter :P